# Python: Pandas - Returning already grouped_by data frame to original data frame

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas data frame as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'col2':[1.0, 2, 3, 4]})
```

This looks like

```
       col1  col2
   0    A     1
   1    A     2
   2    B     3
   3    B     4
```

Below  is a much more simplified version of what I want to do. Suppose I run the below code to group by the data frame on "col1" column and then add another column based on some attribute on the group by condition.

```
gb = df.groupby('col1')

for i in range(len(set(df['col1']))): 
          word_l = [gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups][i]
          l = [1,2]
          word_l['added_col'] = l          #Column added
```

What do I need to do to return this changed `word_l` data frame to the original data frame `df` so that it looks like the below:

```
      col1  col2  added_col
   0    A     1     1
   1    A     2     2
   2    B     3     1
   3    B     4     2
```

Can this be somehow done inside the for loop that I have mentioned? The thing is, there are many other calculations that are being done that need to be done inside the for loop.  I am using the list `l` which is being obtained after many calculations inside the for loop based on some parameters. And the value of `l` changes for each iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have an answer! The trick is to create an empty data frame and append in it.

```
gb = df.groupby('col1')
df1 = pd.DataFrame()        #Create empty data frame
for i in range(len(set(df['col1']))): 
        word_l = [gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups][i]
        l = [1,2]
        word_l['added_col'] = l
        df1 = df1.append(word_l)            #Append in empty data frame
```

The above  gives the desired output:

```
     col1  col2  added_col
 0    A     1          1
 1    A     2          2
 2    B     3          1
 3    B     4          2
```